# Is there any alternative to "last_update_ID()" for mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a big web project using ASP and MySQL.
When inserting into multiple tables I've been using `last_update_ID()`, but after some research I've found that that SQL statement isn't safe.

So. the problem:
I use two different computers, with different internet connections.
Both computers are logged onto the system I am currently building. I have made a page that prints the connection_id(), and last_update_id.
If I update any table with one of the computers the other one also gets that last_update_ID.
Both computers have the same connection_ID.

**What can I do to get around this?**

I don't want to (if it's not necessary) do a select statement after the first INSERT; to search for the row that I inserted, to get the correct ID of that row.

It's not my server I am using so I can't make any large changes of the database.
I guess that this problem occurs because the webpages use the same loginName & password to connect to the database, is that true?

Is there any other alternative to get the last update ID? that is totally safe..
I close every connection at the end of the asp page. but that doesn't change the connection_ID.
The connection ID is the for a few minutes even thou I open up different web pages on the server.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the LAST_INSERT_ID() is correct for the current session. So each session receives it's own correct value. Either I don't understand your question or you think you have a problem but you don't.

I am not aware of any LAST_UPDATE_ID() function, on an update you can easily retrieve the updated rows by SELECTing them with the same WHERE clause (before the update)?

reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most
>   recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis.
>   It is not changed by another client.
>   It is not even changed if you update
>   another AUTO_INCREMENT column with a
>   nonmagic value (that is, a value that
>   is not NULL and not 0). Using
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT
>   columns simultaneously from multiple
>   clients is perfectly valid. Each
>   client will receive the last inserted
>   ID for the last statement *that*
>   client executed.

---

If you want to retrieve the LAST_INSERT_ID from an INSERT query with an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause, you can also use the LAST_INSERT_ID() function to retrieve the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT column that was updated:

reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

> If a table contains an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column and INSERT ... UPDATE inserts a
>   row, the LAST_INSERT_ID() function
>   returns the AUTO_INCREMENT value. If
>   the statement updates a row instead,
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() is not meaningful.
>   However, you can work around this by
>   using LAST_INSERT_ID(expr). Suppose
>   that id is the AUTO_INCREMENT column.
>   To make LAST_INSERT_ID() meaningful
>   for updates, insert rows as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
```

Comment: Actually I still think i have a problem.. I use 2 different computers and 2 different internet connections, and still I am able to retrieve the last_update_ID() from the other computer whem I update or insert into the table.

Comment: Then the answer from grahamparks most probably applies to your case. You are using persistant connections / connection pooling. However they are only used end-to-end. You may want to read up on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Your server appears to have connection pooling turned on. What this means is that the database connection is held open after a script finishes, and the next script that comes along uses it, and thus can see any variables that were set on that connection, including `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

What can't happen is two script instances sharing a connection at the same time. Thus, if your server is busy enough to need to run two script instances at exactly the same time, it will simply create a second database connection, with its own separate `LAST_INSERT_ID()` variable, and won't interfere with the first.

In short, as long as the `INSERT` and the `LAST_INSER_ID()` request happen within the same script (and you don't somehow close the database connection between them), they're completely safe, as your script has exclusive use of that connection.